# Sub-query SQLite Python

Tags: python, sqlite, subquery

Suppose that we have 10 different values of question_id with the value of section_id=1. In another table I have many question_id and each one has 5 unique option_ID. I want to select all the option_id that correspond to the section_id=1. However, when I try the next code I just get the first value of question_id and I can´t find what should be the solution. I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

```
russiandollsel="""
    SELECT option_id FROM option WHERE
        question_id = (SELECT question_id FROM question WHERE section_id=1)
    """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you intended to use `WHERE IN`:

```
SELECT option_id
FROM option WHERE question_id IN (SELECT question_id FROM question WHERE section_id=1)
```

You might also be able to use a join here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.option_id
FROM option o
INNER JOIN question q
    ON on.question_id = q.question_id
WHERE q.section_id = 1
```